# Element with hidden css not changing with javascript .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a dropdown list that I am hiding on initialization since it's not needed unless the client actually selections a specific radiobuttonlist object. I'm presently setting it to false through

```
dlInterval.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] = "hidden";
```

However, attempting to change this through javascript on selection, is failing, at present, I have my code set up to execute as such.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        $("#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID%>").click(function() {
            var intVectorSelectedIndex = $('#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();
            $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID %>").style.visibility="visible";
            if (intVectorSelectedIndex == 1) {
                $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").show();
            } else {
                $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I'm currently attempting to change the visibility from hidden, back to visible, yet I am receiving an error in the browser console '*TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined*'

This doesn't make much sense to me, as the field **should** be hidden, and not just null. What is causing this to happen, and what is a good solution for such a thing?

Comment: Why do you set it to visible, then call show/hide after that? Why not just use `show()`?

Comment: are you sure it's `visibility`? in CSS the corresponding attribute for `.show()`/`.hide()` is `display`.

Comment: It was an attempt to get the visibility to work. Without that line I receive no errors, but the dropdown list still remains hidden.

Comment: Thanks northkildonan, that solved it! If you wouldn't mind writing up the answer, I'll make sure I select it.

Comment: I put CssStyle["display"] = "hidden"  in my answer a while ago

Comment: @trasiva thanks, i posted it as an answer. but I am still not sure how you exactly solved it, since i got no idea about asp.net - maybe choose Scott's answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML attribute is not called `visibility`.

In CSS the corresponding attribute for `.show()` / `.hide()`  is `display`.

Comment: this is true, but jquery does more then just change the css class for display, it has extra code in there to let you manipulate the values of hidden elements

Comment: omg - I understand , was just pointing out that jquery does more then just change a css class , you were right , re-reading my comment it sounded as though I was saying that the answer was not correct , I updated comments

Comment: @ScottSelby afaik jquery `.hide()` sets `display` to `none` and `.show()` back to the value it had originally - for example: `inline-block`.

Comment: @mason - you're right , like I said , updated comment

Answer (score 2):

the code you were looking for is :

```
 dlInterval.Attributes.CssStyle["display"] = "none";
```

or you can just change the javascript to look like,   I personally would think that you should hide the element in javascript if your going to show it in javascript .  Instead of setting the `display:none;` in .Net code that is going to disappear when the page is rendered

just re-write your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        // hide element initially
       $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").hide();     

        $("#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID%>").click(function() {

             // much easier way to check if check box is checked
            if ( $("#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID input[type=radio]:checked%>").is(":checked)) {
                $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").show();
            } else {
                $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

also , I strongly , strongly reccomend using classes to select your html elements with javascript or jquery , .Net mangles the id's and you have to write out this weird syntax to get the proper id,  uses classes prevents all that

NOTE:  if you're going to use this second example then you never need to mess with

```
   dlInterval.Attributes.CssStyle["display"] = "none";
```

Comment: Are you saying that `dlInterval.Attributes.CssStyle[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] = "hidden";` is the equivalent of the calling `dlInterval.Visible=false`? I don't think that's correct at all.

Comment: I actually am not sure ,  I do know that my edit to the answer will fix it regaurdless

Comment: I think you may be correct , I pulled that part out of the answer , as the rest I think will still be found usefull

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense. The problem was entirely on the client side. Not the server. And using inline C# to embed the ID's is perfectly acceptable, if a little ugly. It could be avoided by setting the ClientIDMode to static. There's no need to use CSS classes in this case, which are more appropriate when you want to refer to a collection of objects rather than one element.

Comment: @mason , I have found that different browsers , I forgot which ones , but actually render the ID differently.  I know making a unique class for everything is a lot to do .  but what I used to do personally in web forms was just make classes that are specifically for selecting the elements that all started with underscore and had no actual styling purposes.  This way the javasctipt was cleaner and could be used across different pages.

Comment: No, they do not refer to the ID's differently. If you have an example of that, please post it here. I don't think you're going to find that is the case. Making classes for just that reason is kind of silly when you could set the ClientIDMode at the application or machine level and then use ID's and not have to bother using classes inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use prop and compare if it's true or false? Also, you cant call $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID %>").style.visibility="visible"; you have to call it this way:

For those of you reminiscing on the missing .NET inline ID's here's my modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        var intVectorSelectedIndex = $('#<%=rblVectorChoices.ClientID%>').prop('checked');
        $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").css('visibility', 'visible');
    if (intVectorSelectedIndex == true) {
        $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").show();
    } else {
        $("#<%=dlInterval.ClientID%>").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: don't answer .Net questions if you don't understand it

Comment: I took away my downvote , and it actually was very important here , because OP is using web forms , clearly is new to jquery , and the way you had the id selectors works on every other framework in the world , but not the  specific one that OP was using and because of that it would just lead to more confusion

Comment: I have to admit I acted out of laziness which I shouldn't have. I am fairly new to Stackoverflow and I really appreciate all feedback (specially wrong practices) in my answers. Thanks.